# How to derive the price of a square-or-nothing call option?

Tags: options, pricing, derivation, binary

At maturity $T$, the holder of a "square-or-nothing" call option written on an underlying $S_t$ receives a payoff of the form
$$ \phi(S_T) = \frac{S_T^2}{K} \pmb{1}_{\{S_T \geq K\}} = \begin{cases}\frac{S_T^2}{K}, &\text{ if }\ \ S_T \geq K, \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases} $$

Assume a Black-Scholes diffusion framework where the underlying's risk-neutral drift $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$ are given.

Can one derive a closed-form pricing formula for such an option?

Answer (score 12):

> I provided an answer, based on an elementary approach,  to an exactly same question yesterday. However, that question has disappeared, even though I like to keep a record for what I wrote.  I would suggest that people do not delete their questions as they may be helpful for others. Here, I re-post that answer.

We assume that, under the risk-neutral measure,
\begin{align*}
S_T= S_0e^{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z},
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. Let
\begin{align*}
d_1 = \frac{\ln \frac{S_0}{K} + (\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T }{\sigma\sqrt{T}},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d_2 = \frac{\ln \frac{S_0}{K} + (\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T }{\sigma\sqrt{T}}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT}E\left(\frac{S_T^2}{K}\pmb{1}_{S_T >K} \right) &= \frac{e^{-rT} S_0^2}{K}E\left(e^{(2\mu-\sigma^2)T + 2\sigma \sqrt{T}Z}\pmb{1}_{S_0e^{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z} >K} \right)\\
&= \frac{e^{(-r +2\mu-\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K}E\left(e^{2\sigma \sqrt{T}Z}\pmb{1}_{Z >-d_2} \right)\\
&=\frac{e^{(-r +2\mu-\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K}\int_{-d_2}^{\infty} e^{2\sigma \sqrt{T}z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz\\
&=\frac{e^{(-r +2\mu-\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-d_2}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z- 2\sigma \sqrt{T})^2 + 2 \sigma^2 T} dz\\
&= \frac{e^{(-r +2\mu+\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-d_2- 2\sigma \sqrt{T}}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} dx\\
&= \frac{e^{(-r +2\mu+\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K}\Phi(d_2+ 2\sigma \sqrt{T})\\
&= \frac{e^{(-r +2\mu+\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K}\Phi(d_1+ \sigma \sqrt{T}),
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable.

Comment: Hey, hope I can revive this post a little bit. Could you elaborate a little on how you went from $$\frac{e^{(-r +2\mu-\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-d_2}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z- 2\sigma \sqrt{T})^2 + 2 \sigma^2 T} dz$$ to $$\frac{e^{(-r +2\mu+\sigma^2)T} S_0^2}{K}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-d_2- 2\sigma \sqrt{T}}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} dx$$ I am either not familiar with this type of transformation or I'm missing something simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $x=z-2\sigma\sqrt{T}$, and change the integral limits.

Comment: Yeah, it's the changing of the integral limits that is confusing me. Could you elaborate what exactly happens there? Like is there maybe one extra step in between you could write out to make it more obvious what happens?

Comment: I think this is from the first year calculus. If $z=-d_2$, what is $x$?, and, if $z=\infty$, what will be $x$?

Comment: Ah, I imagined it was something rather simple. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: In your answer, aren't you assuming that the square of stock price process deflated by money market account is a martingale in money market measure, only after which you can assume that discounted claim process is a martingale in that measure, which is what you used? Since the squared stock process is not tradable, why would its discounted process be a martingale?

Comment: The square of the stock price at maturity is the option price. I have never assumed that the deflated  square of the stock price process is a martingale. However, the deflated option price process $V_t = e^{-rT}E(S_T^2\mid \mathscr{F}_t)$ is a martingale.

Comment: Care to look at my question https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/67903/6686? Thanks.

Comment: @Hans: I am not familiar with that. But it appears a first order Taylor expansion, by expanding $K$ around $S_0$.

Comment: @Gordon: I think it expands rather the average $\frac{S+K}2$ around $S_0$. But why?

Comment: @Hans: His book "The Volatility Smile* should be helpful. He basically assumes that the local volatility is the linear form $\sigma(S)= \sigma_0-2\beta(S-S_0)$ and then approximate the implied volatility by the average over $S$ and $K$, that is, $\frac{1}{2}(\sigma(S)+\sigma(K))$.

Comment: @Gordon: Would you mind putting your informative comment below my question so as to benefit more people and for posterity?

Answer (score 8):

See this excellent [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2735944&download=yes) by @MarkJoshi which defines/discusses the use of **power numeraires**.

---

Starting from a dynamics specified under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$

\begin{align}
&\frac{dS_t}{S_t} = (r-q) dt + \sigma dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}}\\
\iff& S_T\ \vert\ \mathcal{F}_t = S_t e^{(r-q-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t) + \sigma(W_T-W_t)} \tag{EQ.0}
\end{align}

Let us consider the asset (power numéraire)

\begin{align}
N_{t,T} :=&\ \ e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[S_T^2\ \vert\ \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
        =&\ \ S_t^2 e^{\left( r - 2q + \sigma^2 \right)(T-t)} > 0,  \forall t \tag{EQ.1} \in [0,T]        
\end{align}

and define the unique equivalent martingale measure $\mathbb{Q}^N$ which uses this asset as numéraire.

From the Girsanov theorem (or using the rationale described in the aforementioned paper), it is straightforward to infer the dynamics of the risky asset $S_t$ under the measure $\mathbb{Q}^N$

$$ \frac{dS_t}{S_t} = (r - q + 2\sigma^2) dt + \sigma dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}^N} \tag{EQ.2}$$

since the Radon-Nikodym happens to compute as

$$ \left. \frac{d\mathbb{Q}^N}{d\mathbb{Q}} \right\vert_{\mathcal{F}_T} = \frac{N_{T,T}\ B_0}{N_{0,T}\ B_T} = \frac{S_T^2}{N_{0,T}\ e^{rT}} = \mathcal{E} \left( 2\sigma W_T^{\mathbb{Q}} \right) \tag{EQ.3} $$

where the notation $\mathcal{E}(X_t)=\exp(X_t-\frac{1}{2}\langle X,X \rangle_t)$ denotes the stochastic exponential.

Now, the price of square-or-nothing option can be evaluated as
\begin{align}
V_0 &= e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q} \left[ \frac{S_T^2}{K} \pmb{1}_{\{ S_T \geq K \}} \ \vert\  \mathcal{F}_0 \right] \\
    &= e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q^N} \left[ \frac{S_T^2}{K} \pmb{1}_{\{ S_T \geq K \}} \left(\frac{d\mathbb{Q}^N}{d\mathbb{Q}}\big|_{\mathcal{F}_T}\right)^{-1}\ \vert\ \mathcal{F}_0 \right]\ \ \ \text{(change of numéraire)} \\
    &= N_{0,T} \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q^N} \left[ \frac{1}{K} \pmb{1}_{\{ S_T \geq K \}}\ \vert\ \mathcal{F}_0 \right]\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(use (EQ.3))} \\
    &= \frac{N_{0,T}}{K} \mathbb{Q^N}(S_T \geq K)
\end{align}

At this stage, because we have shown in $\text{(EQ.2)}$ that $S_T$ was lognormally distributed under $\mathbb{Q}^N$, plugging the definition $\text{(EQ.1)}$ of $N_{0,T}$ finally allows us to re-write the above equation as

\begin{align}
V_0 &= \frac{S_0^2}{K} e^{\left( r - 2q + \sigma^2 \right)T} \Phi( d ) \\
d &= \frac{\ln \left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right) + \left(r-q+\frac{3}{2}\sigma^2\right)T }{\sigma\sqrt{T}}\\
\Phi(x) &= \mathbb{P}(X \leq x),\ X \sim N(0,1)
\end{align} 
which is exactly the result given in @Gordon's answer and in Mark Joshi's paper, see middle of page 3.

Comment: @MarkJoshi and Quantuple, thanks. That is an excellent paper.

Comment: It is :) you are welcome

Comment: I made some changes to (EQ.3) and the step for numeraire change.

Comment: Yes and you are perfectly right, thank you for that :)

Comment: The link to Joshi's paper seems to be dead. Can anyone find it?

Comment: Care to look at my question https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/67903/6686? Thanks.